# How to enable or disable ContextMenu in RadScheduleView

Tags: radscheduler, radmenu

I have a RadSchedule calendar object displayed on my page. I defined a RadContextMenu with a RadMenuItem for the RadSchedule. I want to enable or disable this context menu item based on the appointment type that the user is right clicking.

Currently, the Context Menu always displays.

How can I enable or disable a RadMenuItem?

Comment: after about 2 year i am facing same problem...